# Character Picture Grid Python ATBS index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

I'm a little confused on how to limit my index here without the easy way out of just putting the actual number, but I'm not sure if it's possible with the way my code is right now.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for x in range(len(grid)):
    flip = []
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        flip.append(grid[y][x])
    print (''.join(flip))
```

Results in

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Learning/charPicGrid.py", line 54, in <module>
    flip.append(grid[y][x])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Of course, if I just change it to

```
for x in range(len(grid[0])):
    flip = []
    for y in range(len(grid)):
        flip.append(grid[y][x])
    print (''.join(flip))
```

It will work fine. I could just as well put a number 6 but I'm trying to avoid putting in manual numbers.

Any tips?

Comment: What is the problem in the second approach?

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to just put a flat number in there rather than a dynamic reference so if that the grid changes... though I guess that calling len(grid[0]) for a equally sized lists should always output whatever they are equally sized to...

/shrug I guess if it works here then alright. I am just trying to make sure I understand the subject before I move on